# Why Doesn't the Score Update Properly For My Quiz App

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java/Android developing and I am trying to figure out why my score isn't updating properly on my emulator. I am so sorry if this is obvious– but I cannot figure it out (even after lots of research). Here is my code:

```
package org.flinthill.finalprojectv3;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int Score = 0;


        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button SuSe;
        Button DOS;
        Button B;
        Button BIOS;

        //int Score = 0;

        SuSe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SuSe);
        SuSe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Score = Score * 0;

            }
        });
        DOS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DOS);
        DOS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Score = Score * 0;

            }
        });

        B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B);
        B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Score = Score * 0;

            }
        });
        BIOS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BIOS);
        BIOS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Score = Score ++;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you expecting the score to update? You never update a TextView or toast the score

Comment: I wanted to update it right after I set the new Score number. I could not find the correct method to update it after lots of research...

Comment: Update **where**? Your code looks like it'll add one or multiply by zero perfectly fine

Comment: On my emulator, it, unfortunately, does not update the score.

Comment: what UI View element (widget) are you expecting to update?

Comment: I just changed it to a textview.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Score++;` or `Score = Score + 1;` 
instead of `Score = Score ++;`

Comment: It didn't work... I think I need to add some sort of method to it to make it refresh or something

Comment: Of course you need to call `scoreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(Score));`, after every score change.

Comment: I used an EditText that was set to be not enabled... I do not think this method would work with it. Should I change it back to a TextView? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: If you don't need to make text input by yourself then you should use TextView.

Comment: Is there a special import for the "scoreTextView.setText" method? It says it cannot resolve the "scoreTextView" part of the method.

Comment: No, `setText` method is method on TextView class. Instead of 'scoreTextView' use whatever name you used to declare TextVIew instance. Basically 
`[whatever_is_your_text_view_name].setText(Score);`

Comment: It still is not working for me... this time the "SetText" part is not able to be resolved. (My TextView name is Score and the statement is Score.setText(Score);

Comment: @KamehK `Score` is **not** a TextView. You need a UI element to update with the integer value. Your question doesn't contain one at all, so it's not clear how you expect anything to be *seen updating*

Comment: Are you sure? Im sorry... This is my layout code for it. <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LUL"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />

Comment: Whoops... sorry for the horrible format lol. It is assigned though.